# $IG^2=\dfrac{1}{9}(p^2+5r^2-16Rr).$

Tags: geometry

> Let a triangle have an incenter $I$ and a center $G$. Prove that: $$IG^2=\dfrac{1}{9}(p^2+5r^2-16Rr).$$

Here is what I tried:

> Lemma: Let triangle $ABC$ and a center $G$, a point $M$, then: $$3MG^2=MA^2+MB^2+MC-\dfrac{1}{3}(AB^2+BC^2+CA^2).$$

This can be proved easily by Vector, now we have another lemma:

$$S_{ABC}=\dfrac{abc}{4R}=pr=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$$
$R$: outcenter radius, $r$: incenter radius, $p$: half of the perimeter.

On the other hand, we can calculate $IA,IB,IC$ by pythagorean theorem:

$$IA^2 =r^2+\left(\dfrac{b+c-a}{2}\right)^2$$

But when I use all of them, I can't have the result.

Can anyone help me with those lemma, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what is $p$?

Comment: @calculatormathematical from context of the Heron's formula and $S=pr$, the $p$ is the semiperimeter. Anyway OP you should define all your variables even if they're well-known in geometry.

Comment: It's not, I want a proof